# How to integrate opencv with C++ native of android studio version 3.4.1

Tags: android, opencv

Unable integrate opencv with NDk already Exists project

1. I Imported the module OpenCv in project of exsists project
2. Then I created a native-libs.CPP and cMakelists.txt file Created.It was Working Fine
   3.Then  add a opencvlib in Cmakelists.txt and Add openc2.open.hpp.I Got this Error

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   - What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

     > Build command failed.
     >   Error while executing process C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Users\Lenovo\Pictures\jp\crop\Native\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64 --target native-lib}
     >   [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
     >   FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o 
     >   C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=x86_64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -c ../../../../src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
     >   ../../../../src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found
     >   include 
     >      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     >   please HElp me

Answer (score 0):

opencv mentions that we need to follow following steps to add opencv in native code.

```
// Native C++ support (necessary to use OpenCV in native code of application only):
//
// - Use find_package() in app/CMakeLists.txt:
//
//   find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED java)
//   ...
//   target_link_libraries(native-lib ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
//
// - Add "OpenCV_DIR" and enable C++ exceptions/RTTI support via app/build.gradle
//   Documentation about CMake options: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html
//
//   defaultConfig {
//       ...
//       externalNativeBuild {
//           cmake {
//               cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
//               arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + opencvsdk + "/sdk/native/jni" // , "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
//           }
//       }
//   }
//
// - (optional) Limit/filter ABIs to build ('android' scope of 'app/build.gradle'):
//   Useful information: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html (Configure separate APKs per ABI)
//
//   splits {
//       abi {
//           enable true
//           reset()
//           include 'armeabi-v7a' // , 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
//           universalApk false
//       }
//   }
//
```